# Jenkins Maven Plugin not using environment property for system dependency

Tags: maven, jenkins

I am running into a weird issue, where a "Maven" type job is unable to infer environment for system path
I have defined a weblogic jar as "system" dependency and I provide path to it as a property defined on command line. My pom looks like:
[image]
I have weblogic.home defined in my pom as windows style (for developers), and in my Jenkins job, I pass the server location. In my job job, I run my Maven command as

```
mvn clean package -Dweblogic.home=/systemPath
```

The command works fine when the job is a freestyle job, but it fails when the job is Maven type, with :

> [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.oracle.weblogic:weblogic:jar must specify an absolute path but is C:/localWeblogicPath/server/lib/weblogic.jar @ line 190, column 16

The problem happens irrespective of whether I run the maven command as Maven Build Step, or as post build shell script.

To make matters more confusing, in the build, I run exec-maven-plugin which shows the java class being executed and it shows up that correct weblogic.home is passed to it, as shown in snapshot below:

[image]

Any suggestion on what can I do to make this Maven job pick the right dependency?